# regex error: bad character range 8-1 at position 6

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to map a new value based on characters in a column. These are digits stored as a string.

If the value of the first character is 1 and the second character is `2-10`, then label this as "Lost" etc.

```
print(x[['Segment']].head(15))

   Segment
0       12
1       12
2       22
3       14
4       54
5       12
6       12
7       56
8       12
9       12
10      22
11      12
12     310
13      22
14      53
```

The mapping I will use:

```
segt_map = {
r'[4-5][8-10]': 'Champion',
r'[4-5][4-7]': 'Loyal',
r'[4-5][2-3]': 'Recent',
r'3[6-10]': 'High Potential',
r'3[2-5]': 'Need Nurturing',
r'2[6-10]': 'Cannot Lose',
r'2[2-5]': 'At Risk',
r'1[2-10]': 'Lost',
}
```

And trying to implement it:

```
x['Label'] = x['Segment'].replace(segt_map, regex=True)

error: bad character range 8-1 at position 6
```

I am not sure what my error is, and I've checked the related questions, they're not similar to mine. I looked at position 6, you can see it above.. I can't find a `range 8-1` ? So what is happening here?

The full error trace is quite long, but if it's needed I can post it.

Comment: What do you think the range `8-1` will do? A range (in terms of regex) does not follow the mathematical rules (i.e. numbers from 8-10). Regex is composed of strings.

Comment: 36,37,38,39,310 are 'High Potential' ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character classes match on characters instead of numbers. `[8-10]` means `[8-1]` or `[0]`. You want this:

```
segt_map = {
r'[4-5]([8-9]|10)': 'Champion',
r'[4-5][4-7]': 'Loyal',
r'[4-5][2-3]': 'Recent',
r'3([6-9]|10)': 'High Potential',
r'3[2-5]': 'Need Nurturing',
r'2([6-9]|10)': 'Cannot Lose',
r'2[2-5]': 'At Risk',
r'1([2-9]|10)': 'Lost',
}
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner It depends what this data means. Looking at the original regex, it looks like the first number is distinct from the rest, which would make what you said make sense

Comment: Yes the first number is distinct from the rest

Comment: @SCool Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

You try to use regex to detect number ranges, whereas it's a tool for processing text that knows nothing about numbers. You cannot use range 8-10, because ranges are for characters. It's ok to use `[1-9]`, because it's about chars, but`[1-10]` is incorrect. Instead you should parse text ro numbers and then compare them to rewuired ranges.